# Is defining JavaScript object prototype by simple object is valid - can I use such syntax?

Tags: javascript

I want to find simple way to define JavaScript objects (as object as possible).

1. Can I redefine prototype with object without side effects?
2. Should I use `prototype.member` syntax to avoid side effects?
3. Is all versions will be outlined in Eclipse (with some JsDoc if it required)?

Code example:

```
function Hello() {
    this.name = 'hello';
}

Hello.prototype = {
    hello: function() {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

Comment: var test = new Hello(); test.hello(); gives you "hello". So the syntax is correct and you can create new objects. Is that what you were asking for ?

Comment: @QambarRaza It is not so easy - can be other side effects for example in inheritance. Indeed code will works as you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. The only side effect is that you lose the constructor property of the original prototype object. You might not even use it, but if you do, the solution is easy: add the constructor property yourself:

```
function Hello() {
    this.name = 'hello';
}

Hello.prototype = {
    hello: function() {
        return 'hello';
    },
    constructor: Hello
}
```

Comment: Do you think that is only one possible side effect?

Comment: yea. it's safe to do it.